# A simple builder pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, builder, covariance

I'm implementing a very simple builder pattern for a map-like container:

```
trait KeyValueContainer[K,V] {
  private var props: Map[K, V] = new HashMap[K, V]
  private var built = false

  /**
   * Adds a key/value pair
   */
  def +=(key: K, value: V): KeyValueContainer[K,V] = {
    if (built)
      throw new BuilderException

    props = props + (key -> value)
    this
  }

  def build = {
    built = true
    this
  }
}

class MyContainer extends KeyValueContainer[String, Double]
```

When using the above "+=" or "build" methods on a "new MyContainer()", the result is of type KeyValueContainer[String,Double] in both occassions...

I'm pretty sure I read somewhere in the past that this could be somehow made to return the actual MyContainer sub-type instead. Would you use method return type covariance for this (Java-style), or is there a more type-safe / better solution to this in your view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here it is:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html

The pattern relies on how implicits are resolved at compile-time. Basically, if there are multiple implicits in scope, the compiler picks the most specific one (in your case, the subtype builder you need).

In this way, you can do generic implementations in a base-class and get subclass builders through an implicit argument.

Here is an example of what I did for one of my own projects:

https://gist.github.com/hejfelix/8a0270855d498d7981f9

Another important aspect of this pattern is explicit self-typing:
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124

Comment: No need for such an elaborate construction here. Or in other words, there is no need for implicits in this case. F-bounded polymorphism will do. The key distinction (compared to the places where `CanBuildFrom` is used in the standard library) is that in this case the result type is supposed to always be the same as the original collection.

Comment: Went with def build: this.type = { ... } for my simple builder. +1 for all the extra reading material linked to. Thanks!

Comment: Regis> Oh yes, you are right. I guess it doesn't hurt to learn it now though if he wants to go down this road he will probably (at some time) use a transformation like map or sth.
Nikolaos> I'm happy that you got something useful from it :)

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/kencoba/1874015 This is by far the most clear implementation i have came across.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend this post, it's much simpler, and to the point:

[builder pattern](http://blog.tackley.net/2010/09/option-in-scala-vs-null-in-java.html)

See how by using this.type you can return yourself, and build upon it.

```
trait PaginationParameters extends Parameters {
 var _pageSize: Option[Int] = None
 var _page: Option[Int] = None

 def pageSize(newPageSize: Int): this.type = {
  _pageSize = Some(newPageSize); this
 }

 def page(newPage: Int): this.type  = {
  _page = Some(newPage); this
 }

 override def parameters = super.parameters ++
        _pageSize.map("page-size" -> _) ++
        _page.map("page" -> _)
 }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you do something with this for immutable data structures?